# Couldn't open anaconda and spyder after successful installation of Anaconda 4.2.0 For Windows Python 3.5

Tags: python, windows, qt

I'm using 64 bit Windows 8.1 PC.

I have downloaded Anaconda 4.2.0 For Windows Python 3.5 version 64-BIT INSTALLER.

Please help me out to solve this issue.

C:\Users\Administrator>conda list

# packages in environment at C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3:

```
#
_license                  1.1                      py35_1
_nb_ext_conf              0.3.0                    py35_0
alabaster                 0.7.9                    py35_0
anaconda                  4.2.0               np111py35_0
anaconda-clean            1.0.0                    py35_0
anaconda-client           1.5.1                    py35_0
anaconda-navigator        1.3.1                    py35_0
argcomplete               1.0.0                    py35_1
astroid                   1.4.7                    py35_0
astropy                   1.2.1               np111py35_0
babel                     2.3.4                    py35_0
backports                 1.0                      py35_0
beautifulsoup4            4.5.1                    py35_0
bitarray                  0.8.1                    py35_1
blaze                     0.10.1                   py35_0
bokeh                     0.12.2                   py35_0
boto                      2.42.0                   py35_0
bottleneck                1.1.0               np111py35_0
bzip2                     1.0.6                    vc14_3  [vc14]
cffi                      1.7.0                    py35_0
chest                     0.2.3                    py35_0
click                     6.6                      py35_0
cloudpickle               0.2.1                    py35_0
clyent                    1.2.2                    py35_0
colorama                  0.3.7                    py35_0
comtypes                  1.1.2                    py35_0
conda                     4.2.9                    py35_0
conda-build               2.0.2                    py35_0
configobj                 5.0.6                    py35_0
console_shortcut          0.1.1                    py35_1
contextlib2               0.5.3                    py35_0
cryptography              1.5                      py35_0
curl                      7.49.0                   vc14_0  [vc14]
cycler                    0.10.0                   py35_0
cython                    0.24.1                   py35_0
cytoolz                   0.8.0                    py35_0
dask                      0.11.0                   py35_0
datashape                 0.5.2                    py35_0
decorator                 4.0.10                   py35_0
dill                      0.2.5                    py35_0
docutils                  0.12                     py35_2
dynd-python               0.7.2                    py35_0
entrypoints               0.2.2                    py35_0
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py35_0
fastcache                 1.0.2                    py35_1
filelock                  2.0.6                    py35_0
flask                     0.11.1                   py35_0
flask-cors                2.1.2                    py35_0
freetype                  2.5.5                    vc14_1  [vc14]
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                    py35_0
gevent                    1.1.2                    py35_0
greenlet                  0.4.10                   py35_0
h5py                      2.6.0               np111py35_2
hdf5                      1.8.15.1                 vc14_4  [vc14]
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py35_1
icu                       57.1                     vc14_0  [vc14]
idna                      2.1                      py35_0
imagesize                 0.7.1                    py35_0
ipykernel                 4.5.0                    py35_0
ipython                   5.1.0                    py35_0
ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py35_0
ipywidgets                5.2.2                    py35_0
itsdangerous              0.24                     py35_0
jdcal                     1.2                      py35_1
jedi                      0.9.0                    py35_1
jinja2                    2.8                      py35_1
jpeg                      8d                       vc14_2  [vc14]
jsonschema                2.5.1                    py35_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py35_3
jupyter_client            4.4.0                    py35_0
jupyter_console           5.0.0                    py35_0
jupyter_core              4.2.0                    py35_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.2.1                    py35_0
libdynd                   0.7.2                         0
libpng                    1.6.22                   vc14_0  [vc14]
libtiff                   4.0.6                    vc14_2  [vc14]
llvmlite                  0.13.0                   py35_0
locket                    0.2.0                    py35_1
lxml                      3.6.4                    py35_0
markupsafe                0.23                     py35_2
matplotlib                1.5.3               np111py35_0
menuinst                  1.4.1                    py35_0
mistune                   0.7.3                    py35_0
mkl                       11.3.3                        1
mkl-service               1.1.2                    py35_2
mpmath                    0.19                     py35_1
multipledispatch          0.4.8                    py35_0
nb_anacondacloud          1.2.0                    py35_0
nb_conda                  2.0.0                    py35_0
nb_conda_kernels          2.0.0                    py35_0
nbconvert                 4.2.0                    py35_0
nbformat                  4.1.0                    py35_0
nbpresent                 3.0.2                    py35_0
networkx                  1.11                     py35_0
nltk                      3.2.1                    py35_0
nose                      1.3.7                    py35_1
notebook                  4.2.3                    py35_0
numba                     0.28.1              np111py35_0
numexpr                   2.6.1               np111py35_0
numpy                     1.11.1                   py35_1
odo                       0.5.0                    py35_1
openpyxl                  2.3.2                    py35_0
openssl                   1.0.2j                   vc14_0  [vc14]
pandas                    0.18.1              np111py35_0
partd                     0.3.6                    py35_0
path.py                   8.2.1                    py35_0
pathlib2                  2.1.0                    py35_0
patsy                     0.4.1                    py35_0
pep8                      1.7.0                    py35_0
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py35_0
pillow                    3.3.1                    py35_0
pip                       8.1.2                    py35_0
pkginfo                   1.3.2                    py35_0
ply                       3.9                      py35_0
prompt_toolkit            1.0.3                    py35_0
psutil                    4.3.1                    py35_0
py                        1.4.31                   py35_0
pyasn1                    0.1.9                    py35_0
pycosat                   0.6.1                    py35_1
pycparser                 2.14                     py35_1
pycrypto                  2.6.1                    py35_4
pycurl                    7.43.0                   py35_0
pyflakes                  1.3.0                    py35_0
pygments                  2.1.3                    py35_0
pylint                    1.5.4                    py35_1
pyopenssl                 16.0.0                   py35_0
pyparsing                 2.1.4                    py35_0
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py35_0
pytables                  3.2.2               np111py35_4
pytest                    2.9.2                    py35_0
python                    3.5.2                         0
python-dateutil           2.5.3                    py35_0
pytz                      2016.6.1                 py35_0
pywin32                   220                      py35_1
pyyaml                    3.12                     py35_0
pyzmq                     15.4.0                   py35_0
qtawesome                 0.3.3                    py35_0
qtconsole                 4.2.1                    py35_2
qtpy                      1.1.2                    py35_0
requests                  2.11.1                   py35_0
rope                      0.9.4                    py35_1
ruamel_yaml               0.11.14                  py35_0
scikit-image              0.12.3              np111py35_1
scikit-learn              0.17.1              np111py35_1
scipy                     0.18.1              np111py35_0
setuptools                27.2.0                   py35_1
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py35_1
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py35_0
sip                       4.18                     py35_0
six                       1.10.0                   py35_0
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py35_0
sockjs-tornado            1.0.3                    py35_0
sphinx                    1.4.6                    py35_0
spyder                    3.0.0                    py35_0
sqlalchemy                1.0.13                   py35_0
statsmodels               0.6.1               np111py35_1
sympy                     1.0                      py35_0
tk                        8.5.18                   vc14_0  [vc14]
toolz                     0.8.0                    py35_0
tornado                   4.4.1                    py35_0
traitlets                 4.3.0                    py35_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py35_0
vs2015_runtime            14.0.25123                    0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py35_0
werkzeug                  0.11.11                  py35_0
wheel                     0.29.0                   py35_0
widgetsnbextension        1.2.6                    py35_0
win_unicode_console       0.5                      py35_0
wrapt                     1.10.6                   py35_0
xlrd                      1.0.0                    py35_0
xlsxwriter                0.9.3                    py35_0
xlwings                   0.10.0                   py35_0
xlwt                      1.1.2                    py35_0
zlib                      1.2.8                    vc14_3  [vc14]
```

C:\Users\Administrator>conda info
Current conda install:

```
           platform : win-64
      conda version : 4.2.9
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.2.9
conda-build version : 2.0.2
     python version : 3.5.2.final.0
   requests version : 2.11.1
   root environment : C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3  (writable)
default environment : C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3
   envs directories : C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\envs
      package cache : C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch/
        config file : None
       offline mode : False
```

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>qmake --version

```
[![QMake version 3.0                                                           
Using Qt version 5.6.0 in C:/Users/ray/qt5-x64-3.5/envs/_build/Library/lib][1]][1]
```

**Environment Variables:**

*User variables for Administrator:*

*Variable:*

PATH

*Value:*

C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\Library\bin;

*System Variables:*

*Variable:*

PATH

*Value:*

C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\

Comment: What error message you gets?